# Memory overflow(?) crash on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a game for myself. The problem I am stuck with is that for some reason the program crashes after putting some objects on a canvas and deleting them. More in-depth:

I have the frame `FrameMain` with a canvas in it.

I have the frame `FrameLower` with a canvas in it. Also an image on canvas.

I am placing and deleting few `FrameLower` as `FrameMain.obj` on `FrameMain` canvas with `FrameMain.__placeFrames()` method.

The problem is that it seems like memory somewhere does not get cleared completely when I delete `FrameMain.obj`. So it leads to the program crashing after a while, depending on how many times `FrameLower` is placed and how many images it has on its canvas.

I have enough free RAM, as you can predict, ~6GB, so that's not a problem.

What I really want to understand is why it is crashing if there's free memory to store the objects and why those objects do not get deleted completely.

What I really want to do is get rid of this crash. In the following simplified example, I am placing 10000 frames, but in real program 100 of them is enough to kill my game - they are heavily filled with images.

(For this code to work as-is, any `img.gif` file in the root directory is needed)

```
from tkinter import *

class FrameMain(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master,height=100,width=100,bg='black')
        self.grid()

        self.canvas=Canvas(self,height=100,width=100,bg='white')
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.__placeFrames(10000)

    def __placeFrames(self,number):
        for counter in range(0,number):
            self.obj=self.canvas.create_window(50,50,window=FrameLower(self.canvas))
            self.canvas.delete(self.obj)
            del self.obj



class FrameLower(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master,height=50,width=50,bg='red')

        self.canvas=Canvas(self,height=50,width=50,bg='blue')
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.img=PhotoImage(file='img.gif')
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.img)

def Run():
    root=Tk()
    frameMain=FrameMain(root)
    root.mainloop()

Run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [mcve] to improve your queston.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Thanks alot for pointing this out. I've tried to simplify my code as much as it possible and added more in-depth description of a problem. Hope someone will help me out of trouble. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `self.canvas.delete(self.obj)`, all you're doing is deleting the object from the canvas. The frame that is associated with the object will not be destroyed. If you want to destroy the window object, you need to explicitly call `destroy` on it.

The canvas also has some known limitations when creating thousands upon thousands of items. It doesn't recycle canvas item ids, so they continue to take up a tiny amount of memory even if the canvas object itself has been removed. One solution to this is to not delete canvas items, but rather move them off-screen or configure them to be hidden when they are not needed, and then reconfigure them instead of creating a new item.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation of python mechanics behind this issue. I was able to fix this problem by adding `self.frm=FrameLower(self.canvas)` and
`self.frm.destroy()` lines, and got the general solution of how to avoid this type of issues in future. =)